# Kernel panic after changing CPU and motherboard

Tags: debian, kernel-panic

I replaced my Gigabyte GA-Z170M-D3H with a MSI B450 Tomahawk.

I replaced my Intel Core i7-6700 with an AMD Ryzen 5.

I have Debian 9.x on an SSD. I forget the exact version number of the operating system.

I also have Windows 10 on another SSD.

When I booted up my computer after installing the new parts, the GRUB menu popped up. When I selected Windows 10, the OS detected the new parts and adapted without error.

But when I select Debian, I get a message about a loop and eventually run into kernel panic.

```
0
   4.423328] Call Trace:
   4.423391]  <IRQ> [    4.423451]  [<ffffffff9bae0916>] ? rcu_process_callbac
+0x1e6/0x5b0
   4.423582]  [<ffffffff9c0186ba>] ? __do_softirq+0x10a/0x29e
   4.423654]  [<ffffffff9ba7eefe>] ? irq_exit+0xae/0xb0
   4.423724]  [<ffffffff9c018184>] ? smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x44/0x50
   4.423724]  [<ffffffff9c016a76>] ? apic_timer_interrupt+0x96/0xa0
   4.423876]  <EOI> [    4.423935]  [<ffffffff9bed7182>] ? cpuidle_enter_state
xa2/0x2d0
   4.424065]  [<ffffffff9bed7170>] ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x90/0x2d0
   4.424138]  [<ffffffff9babbd24>] ? cpu_startup_entry+0x154/0x240
   4.424210]  [<ffffffff9ba48bb0>] ? start_secondary+0x170/0x1b0
   4.424282] Code: e9 c0 a6 f1 ff b8 f2 ff ff ff 66 31 d2 e9 78 c9 fe ff ba f2
f ff ff e9 37 ca fe ff 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 0f ae e8 <ff> e0 0f
f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 40 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 66 2e
   4.427833] RIP  [<ffffffff9c01ab03>] __x86_indirect_thunk_rax+0x3/0x20
   4.427833]  RSP <ffffa00d9e8c3f20>
   4.428029] ---[ end trace fabd71bf0ebd09e3 ]---
   4.428097] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
   4.551823] AMD-Vi: Completion-Wait loop timed out
   4.551896] Kernel Offset: 0x1aa00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation ran
: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
   4.551986] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
```

How do I make Debian adapt to my new parts and boot properly?

Comment: First time I hear that Windows accepted such a hardware change and Linux didn't seem so, but you certainly aren't waiting for an answer today.
I'd have suggested a bios update and to check if a live debian 9 system would boot fine, as your system could just not be supported yet.
Your console the stack trace suggests to me that you were having trouble with power management of some device, so changing a few related bios settings could make it work.

Comment: Older versions of the Linux kernel (which Debian uses) has a bug on older Ryzen processors.  I haven't heard of a kernel panic though.  A Ryzen 3xxx is not affected IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

The B450 was released 9 months after Debian 9, so it would virtually certainly need a backported Debian 10 or other >4.15 kernel, or an upgrade to Debian 10, to support it.